# Remove unnecessary memory allocation during serialization

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a wrapper class holding a protobuf as a private member, `myInstance`. The protobuf contains an `optional bytes payload` which i want to set using a function template in the wrapper class (making the wrapper class payload agnostic until template instantiation).

I wrote this set_payload function in the wrapper class:

```
  template <typename T>
  inline void set_payload(const T& somePayload)
  {
    uint32_t payloadSize = somePayload.ByteSize();
    uint8_t* serializedPayload = new uint8_t[payloadSize];
    somePayload.SerializeToArray(serializedPayload, payloadSize);
    myInstance->set_payload(serializedPayload, payloadSize);
    delete [] serializedPayload;
  }
```

This function can take any protobuf and serialize it into the `payload` member of `myInstance` inside the wrapper class.

My problem is the extra memory allocation step. I would like to remove the use of new and delete inside the function template, as this memory will be allocated for `myInstance::payload` anyways. Possible?

The identity of the function could have been `inline void set_payload(const ::google::protobuf::Message& somePayload)` instead, without being a template. Same implementation.

Comment: What is `myInstance` exactly? What is `myInstance->set_payload`? I cannot find such method in google protobuf sources.

Comment: As i wrote above, myInstance has an optional bytes payload. And given this there will be a generated setter called set_payload in myInstance, which takes a pointer to data and a size. This data will then be copied into payload (a bytes field is realized by an std::string)

Comment: oh sorry this is a generated class. Didn't realise that at first. The latest version of protobuf ought to have *move-aware setters* so you can make `serializedPayload` an `std::string` of an appropriate size, get its `char` data, call `SerializeToArray` on it and then call `myInstance -> set_payload(std::move(serializedPayload));` Please tell me if this works for you.

Comment: In unrelated news, it looks like `optional` fields are implemented with pointers so there's an `std::string* payload` class member and `set_payload` will call `new std::string`. This would be rather suboptimal. You may want to try making the field not optional.

Comment: Your suggestion works. I had a hard time at first because i used reserve to resize the string, but with resize it works like a charm. Not sure exactly what reserve is used for :)

Comment: reserve is a hint for the library, it says the string is likely to grow this big in the future.

Comment: I guess i don't actually know if the move removes one memory re-allocation even if it works from a functional point of view, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146154/discussion-between-n-m-and-martin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protobuf now has *move-aware setters* that accept rvalue references.

In order to use a move-aware setter for `payload`, you need to do something like this:

1. make `serializedPayload` a `std::string`

   ```
   std::string payload;
   ```
2. grow it to needed size:

   ```
    payload.resize(payloadSize);
   ```
3. serialize to its data:

   ```
   somePayload.SerializeToArray(payload.data(), payloadSize); // c++17, or
   somePayload.SerializeToArray(&payload[0], payloadSize); // c++<17
   ```
4. call the move-aware setter:

   ```
   myInstance->set_payload(std::move(serializedPayload), payloadSize);
   ```

Comment: somePayload.SerializeToArray(const_cast<char*>(payload.data()), payloadSize);